# Short term exact solution to semilinear heat equation $u_{t}=u_{xx}+u^{2}$ with periodic boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The semilinear heat equation  $u_{t}=u_{xx}+u^{2}$ blows up in finite time, that depends on the initial condition.

But I was wondering if it has an exact solution up to that time?

The equation is $u_{t}=u_{xx}+u^{2}$ in $(-\pi,\pi)$ with periodic initial data say $u_{0}(x)=cos(x)$.

I need it because I want to test the accuracy of the pseudospectral method.